# Decode Firebase/Google JWT

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I get a JWT from firebase over my custom auth system with this command:

```
firebase.auth().createCustomToken(uid)
```

To check if the Token expired i would decode with the "jsonwebtoken" package, but when i do this i get the following error:

```
[Error: PEM_read_bio_PUBKEY failed]
```

I think it is a format problem of the Private Key that i get from the google cloud service account, but i don't know how can i format this correct.

I'm grateful for an idea.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase custom token authentication (firebase version 3)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38186897/firebase-custom-token-authentication-firebase-version-3)