# Firebase custom token authentication (firebase version 3)

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have an authentication server (NodeJS) where I authenticate a user and create a custom firebase token

```
   var token = firebase.auth().createCustomToken(userId);
```

I used to be able to verify a user token (previous version), but now it is not so simple...

I would like to get the decoded userId from the token

```
  firebase.auth().verifyIdToken(token).then(function)....
```

does not work for server generated custom tokens.

Does anyone know how this could be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be using `jsonwebtoken` to validate the token in this case. You will just need to pass the firebase private key as an additional parameter.

```
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var fbPrivateKey = //your firebase key string here 
jwt.verify(token, fbPrivateKey, { algorithms: ['RS256'] }, function(err, decoded) {
    console.log(decoded); //your token info will be available here.
});
```

### Update:

You have to use the `private_key` from the `.json` config file that you set in `firebase.initializeApp({` and use a library to convert this key to the `public PEM format`. You can use [node-rsa](https://github.com/rzcoder/node-rsa) to do the trick

```
var NodeRSA = require('node-rsa');
var fbPrivateKey = //key from the .json file.
var key = new NodeRSA(fbPrivateKey).exportKey('pkcs8-public-pem');
jwt.verify(token, key, { algorithms: ['RS256'] }, function(err, decoded) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(decoded); //your token info will be available here.
});
```

Comment: Tried that, I got "invalid algorithm, JsonWebTokenError"

Comment: I got "PEM_read_bio_PUBKEY"

could this be because of the private key format ?

Comment: @Dev138 Just did it! Let me know if you still have any doubts.

Comment: Hey @Dev138 let me know if you made it.

Comment: sorry it took me so long
but no it still doesn't work, could I be using the wrong key format ?
I got this error " Key format must be specified"

could you give an example of a valid fbPrivate key? ( change the letters ofcourse)

I use one of the firebase secrets connected to my account "U3JN6hLvRWFlm3ipus1nEQ79Nm2n6xH61b140MBl"

Comment: @Dev138 how are you initiating your firebase connection? You should be using a .json file that you download. There you will find the private_key. Its a large one that starts with -----BEGIN...

Comment: WORKS! I dont belive I put the wrong key..

thank you

Comment: Using NodeRSA to convert the private key in in the service account .json config file to the public PEM format worked for me as well.

Comment: Thank you so very much! I couldn't for the life of me figure out how to verify a custom token before I found this post. Can someone explain what     new NodeRSA(fbPrivateKey).exportKey('pkcs8-public-pem')    does, and why the private key is encoded?

Comment: Followed @adolfosrs 'update' exactly but I get this error: "JsonWebTokenError: invalid signature". Any ideas people?

Comment: I have same problem with @HarryLincoln